# Fundamental groupoid of a filtered union

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, fundamental-groups, limits-colimits, groupoids

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ be a filtered family of subspaces. Let $X =\bigcup_{i \in I} X^°_i$ be the union of the interiors of the $X_i$. I want to prove the following statements:

- $\Pi_1(X) \cong \text{colim}_{i \in I} \Pi_1(Xi)$
- If $x \in \bigcap_{i \in I} X_i$, $\pi_1(X,x) \cong \text{colim}_{i \in I} \pi_1(X_i, x)$

So, to start, I want to show that $\Pi_1(X)$ satisfies the universal property of colimits in the category of groupoids. Hence, I consider a general groupoid $\Gamma$ with $h_i: \Pi_1(X_i) \to \Gamma, h_j: \Pi_1(X_j) \to \Gamma$, and look for the existence of a unique morphism $h: \Pi_1(X) \to  \Gamma$ making the right triangles commute (where the map from $\Pi_1(X_i)$ to $\Pi_1(X)$ are just $\Pi_1(\iota_i)$, $\iota: X_i \to X$ being the inclusion, and similarly for $ \Pi_1(\iota_{ij}): \Pi_1(X_i) \to \Pi_1(X_j)$ for $i \leq j$).

Regarding the objects of $\Pi_1(X)$, these are just the points of $X$, thus if $x \in X$ then $x \in X_i$ for some $i \in I$, we are forced to set $h(x)=h_i(x)$ (I think?)

On morphisms: if I take a path $\gamma: I \to X$ in $X$, by compactness of $I$ I can show that $\gamma(I) \subseteq X_i$ for some $i \in I$, hence I can regard $\gamma$ as a path in $X_i$.

I would like to say that, if $h$ exists, then it must happen that $h([\gamma])=h_i([\gamma])$. In this case, $h$ would be uniquely determined. But what happens if $\gamma(I) \subseteq X_j \subseteq X_i$? Does it follow from the commutativity of the diagram that $h_j([\gamma])=h_i[\gamma])$? Can I use this as my definition of $h$?

Functoriality would come from the functoriality of $h_i$. Now, I know how to prove that if two loops are homotopic in $X$, then they are already homotopic in $X_k$ for some $k \in I$ (again by a compactness argument). Thus, if I take $\gamma, \alpha: I \to X$ such that they are homotopic in $X$, then from above we know that $\gamma: I \to X_i$ and $\alpha: I \to X_j$ for some $i, j \in I$, and from the filtered property we get that they are indeed homotopic in some $X_k, i,j \leq k$.

I would like to use this remark to show that $h$ depends only on the homotopy class of the path. The problem is that the I do not know how to incorporate this new $k \in I$ for which the two paths are homotopic in $X_k$, hence I am afraid that I am making some mistakes at the very beginning.

I can see that every morphism of $\Pi_1(X)$ and every pointed homotopy between such morphisms already lives in one of the subspaces $X_i$, but I don't understand how from these conditions I can get that $X$ is indeed the colimit.

I am completely lost now, thus any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest that you (a) find a description of the filtered colimit of groupoids (this is rather easy and works with all filtered diagrams; but please notice that the transition functors are *not* faithful here), (b) show that the canonical morphism / functor (it exists by the universal property of the colimit) from the colimit to $\Pi_1(X)$ is an equivalence (this is *not* easy and may actually require additional assumptions on the space $X$). So don't verify the universal property.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thank you for your input. Unfortunately I don't have a strong background of category theory, and the aim of this exercise is not to work with explicit colimits in Grpd but to somehow mimic the proof of Seifert-van Kampen theorem. Do you think that my approach would possibly be correct?

Comment: The issue with proving the universal property is that it adds extra complexity. You have to deal with another groupoid $D$ and show that compatible functors $\Pi(X_i) \to D$ lift to a functor $\Pi(X) \to D$. In the end, the purely topological arguments remain the same. I think that the statement is much easier than Seifert van Kampen, because here we don't need to go "back and forth" between the summands. It is just about going "far enough" to the top.

Comment: The definition of $h$ is correct. For the second part, if $\alpha$ is a path contained in $X_i$, $\beta$ contained in $X_j$ and the homotopy between them contained in $X_k$ then use the fact that the system is filtered that there is $X_l$ that contains, $X_i, X_j$ and $X_k$. I think the argument for the fundamental group is essentially the same.

Comment: @VincentBoelens I see. Then, my doubt probably regards the fact that the map $h$ is well-defined. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the two  paths in $X_i$, $X_j$ that are homotopic in $X$, and, as you said, I consider $X_l$ containing $X_i, X_j$ such that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are homotopic in $X_l$... why does it hold that $h([\alpha])=h([\beta])$? Does $h_i([\alpha])=h_l([\alpha])$ for $X_i \subseteq X_l$ come from the commutativity of the diagram? Maybe I am lost in something trivial.

Comment: Yes, it comes from the commutativity of the diagram.